# Why Request doesn't work on a specific URL?

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a question re: requests module in Python.

So far I have been using this to scrape and it's been working well.

However when I do it against one particular website (code below - and refer to the Jupyter Notebook snapshot), it just doesn't want to complete the task (showing [*] forever).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

page = requests.get('https://www.stoneisland.com/ca/stone-island-shadow-project/coats-jackets', verify = False)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

Some users also suggest using headers such as below to speed it up but it doesnt work for me as well:

```
url = 'https://www.stoneisland.com/ca/stone-island-shadow-project/coats-jackets'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3'}

req = requests.get(url = url, headers = headers)
```

Not sure what's going on (this is the first time for me) but I might be missing on something obvious. If someone can explain why this is not working? Or if it's working in your machine, please do let me know!

[image: weird_requests]

Comment: It's not you. Looks like a server-side issue. The website is not accessible from a bunch of other sources I tried.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. Anything we can do to bypass this issue in python? I'm thinking copying all the html in text format then somehow pass it back to python / beautiful soup.. is this possible?

Comment: ok manage to bypass this issue by manually copying the html into html file then opening it with beautiful soup. If there's any other automated alternative let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The page attempts to add a cookie the first time you visit it. By using the requests module and not defining a cookie will prevent you from being able to connect to the page.

I've modified your script to include my cookie which should work - if it doesn't, copy your cookie (for this host domain) from the browser to the script.

```
url = 'https://www.stoneisland.com/ca/stone-island-shadow-project/coats-jackets'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3'}

cookies = {
    'TS01e58ec0': '01a1c9e334eb0b8b191d36d0da302b2bca8927a0ffd2565884aff3ce69db2486850b7fb8e283001c711cc882a8d1f749838ff59d3d'
}

req = requests.get(url = url, headers = headers, cookies=cookies)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but it still doesn't work.. I've modified with my own cookie :(

Comment: @umm What error are you getting? It still works for me (returns a 41269 Content-Length response with all the links intact)